# Creating user registration/login website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, registration

I thought of creating a website where users can register and login to their accounts. I want to use the Ruby language combined with my html/css/javascript/jquery knowledge. The problem is I don't know how or where to start.

Of course I'll need a database, maybe MySQL? 
I read about Devise, I have no idea how these work.

In short, I want to be able to create a form (this I can do) that will store registered users in a database and make them able able to login to check their accounts and do some stuff.

What am I missing? What do I need to do? Can someone please point in the beset direction how to start something like this?

Comment: Learn Ruby, then start looking at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com), which will give you an understanding of applying Ruby to web tasks. Once you're comfortable with how Sinatra works you'll be in a good spot to begin working with Rails. Rails uses a lot of Ruby's more advanced features, which, if you don't understand object-oriented programming, introspection and dynamically defining methods at run-time, will just seem like so much voodoo and black-magic.

Comment: I already know Ruby and can basically do anything I can with Java with it. I know OOP. I'll follow your advice and check Sinatra/Rails. But I understand they are both frameworks...does this mean one is easier/better than the other? And can't I do with Rails what I can with Sinatra?

Comment: Sinatra isn't a framework, it's a DSL that sits on top of Rack. It's a great prototyping tool for Ruby-based web-developers which also can handle a decent amount of traffic. I use it regularly at work for internal websites. Rails also sits on top of Rack, but it's a full framework with a much steeper learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

For a database, look at starting with [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org). It's plenty capable for your initial experiments.

To test using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org), I recommend using the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) ORM ("[Object Relational Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)") gem. The big advantage to using Sequel is you don't have to learn SQL or a query language to talk to the database right away. You can concentrate on getting your code working instead. Sequel is also a great shim-layer between your code and the database, that abstracts the specifics of connecting and talking to it, making it easy to move from one type of database to another with no, or very minimal, changes to your code.

Look at using [HAML](http://haml.info) with Sinatra for generating your HTML. It's a great templating engine for HTML that can really clean up your HTML and ease the task of embedding Ruby's variables or control structures.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to work in Ruby On Rails framework which is a framework developed by Ruby language.

You can get the tutorial [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)

You can check the video tutorials here in [railscast](http://railscasts.com/)

It will be easy after learning Ruby on Rails

Comment: Without an understanding of Ruby, Rails will be a very steep learning curve.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I checked your links and will dive more into it.